# PyPandoc in combination with PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, pandoc, pypandoc

I installed PyInstaller to create executables for my python scripts, and that works fine. I used PyPandoc to create `.docx` reports, which also run fine when the normal python files are run, but not from the PyInstaller generated executable. It gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src\flexmodel_postcalc.py", line 295, in postcalculate_everything
  File "src\flexmodel_postcalc.py", line 281, in generate_report_docx
  File "src\flexmodel_report_docx.py", line 118, in generate_text_useages_docx
  File "pypandoc\__init__.py", line 50, in convert
  File "pypandoc\__init__.py", line 70, in _convert
  File "pypandoc\__init__.py", line 197, in get_pandoc_formats
  File "pypandoc\__init__.py", line 336, in _ensure_pandoc_path
OSError: No pandoc was found: either install pandoc and add it
to your PATH or install pypandoc wheels with included pandoc.
```

During the executable creation I see no strange issues about PyPandoc. How can I include Pandoc into my executable so others (without Python and/or Pandoc installation) can use the executable and create `.docx` reports?

edit: a working process included the following steps:

1. Create a file including the following code:

   ```
   import pypandoc
   pypandoc.convert(sou‌​rce='# Sample title\nPlaceholder', to='docx', format='md', outputfile='test.doc‌​x')
   ```
2. Save this file as `pythonfile.py`
3. create an executable with PyInstaller:

   ```
   pyinstaller --onefile --clean pythonfile.py
   ```
4. Now the executable should run on a computer without Pandoc (or PyPandoc) installed.

Comment: Can you add a minimal working example of your python script to see which part of pandoc you are using? I tried with `pypandoc` only and seems to be working fine in my windows system. Most likely you need to add `pypandoc` as a [hidden import](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports) plus some other dependecy.

Comment: @Repiklis I can give a very short sample code, but not test it right now. `import pypandoc; pypandoc.convert(source='# Sample title\nPlaceholder', to='docx', format='md', outputfile='test.docx')`. This is saved in a `.py` file, which I convert with PyInstaller via the command `pyinstaller --onefile --clean -p H:\AppData\Python\Python27\Lib\site-packages pythonfile.py`

Comment: Please post your sample code in the question to allow others to understand your issue. I'll post an answer below.

Comment: @Repiklis added it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here. The first one is that `pypandoc` needs `pandoc.exe` to work. This is not picked up by `pyinstaller` automatically, but you can specify it manually.

To do this you you have to [create a `.spec` file](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#using-spec-files). The one I generated and used looks like this:

```
block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['pythonfile.py'],
             pathex=['CodeDIR'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='EXEName',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True , 
          resources=['YourPandocLocationHere\\\\pandoc.exe'])
```

You can build the executable by using `pyinstaller myspec.spec`. Don't forget to change the paths and the `name` parameter.

If you were building that in a directory mode this should be enough. However, for the `one-file` mode, things are a bit more complicated due to the way the pyinstaller [bootloader process](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/advanced-topics.html#bootloader) works. The `pandoc.exe` file is unzipped during execution in a temporary folder, but the execution happens in your original `.exe` folder. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674790/bundling-data-files-with-pyinstaller-onefile), you have to add the following lines to your code before calling pypandoc to change your current folder, if you run the frozen code.

```
if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
    os.chdir(sys._MEIPASS)
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I have not got the `-p` argument working for some reason, but at least I am on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: You have to add a [`collect` block](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/spec-files.html#spec-file-operation) at the end of the `.spec` file in order to compile as a `one-dir`.

Comment: Is it correct that the `resources` argument should not be a list? I get a TypeError with is, and without the `[]` it works. For future reference, I included the `-p` argument folder in the `pathex` argument (a new item in that list).